# Bootstrap Modal Component not showing data from Angular Controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope

I am using vanilla Angular JS without angular-ui module. I have an object on the controller as $scope.spotDetails. I verified that it has data in it. I want to show this data on the view that is tied to this controller on a modal. Rest of the page shows other data from the controller but when I open the modal, it does not show the data from the aforementioned object.

Here is the controller code

```
chaloApp.controller('planController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', '$location', '$compile', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $cookies, $location, $compile){


      $scope.spot = {};
      //the object which holds the getDetails method call response from Google
      $scope.spotDetails = {};
.....
```

Modal HTML

```
......
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                     <div class="modal-content">
                       <div class="modal-header">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                         <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-body">
                         {{ spotDetails.name }}
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-footer">
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                 </div>
```

Been trying to look online everywhere for an answer but can't find one. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Is your modal element under the element of the controller? You need to place the modal element under the controller element to use the controller's scope in the modal. I recommend you to use ui-bootstrap though.

Comment: @ShuheiKagawa ...I started looking into Angular-UI-Bootstrap cuz I figured it must be something to do with Modal not being part of the scope. I will use ui-bootstrap, thanks. I am loading the view with Angular routing and connected it with the controller so still not sure why it should not work. Is the modal not part of the scope of the view it is embedded in usually. I read somewhere I may have to compile it for it to be part of the scope.